# Proving the following subgroup(verification of logic)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

So I was reading the following theorem from dummit that is 
If $|H| = n <\infty$ then for each positive integer dividing n there is a unique subgroup of $H$ of order $a$. This subgroup is the cyclic group $<x^d>$ , where $d = \frac{n}{a}$. Furthermore for every integer $m$, $<x^{m}> = <x^{(n,m)}>$ so that the subgroups of H correspond bijectively with the positive divisors of n.

So I understand the proof but they did't show that

$<x^m>$ is a subgroup of   $<x^{(n,m)}>$.

My reasoning is that is that we have $(n,m) = d$ so $d \mid n$ and $d \mid m$ , since $d$ divides $m$, $x^{m} \in <x^{d}>$ and since they have same order so they must be the same.

I would like to also if someone could explain to me the intuition behind this theorem as I understand it but would like to hear what other people understanding of this aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, for a cyclic group of order $n$, there is a subgroup of order $n/d$ where $d>0$ and $d\mid n$.

Some intuition behind this:

Looking at the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ we would expect that if $d\mid n$ that $d+\ldots +d=0$ would be a sum of shorter length than $1+\ldots + 1=0$. But this is exactly the same as having a subgroup of order $n/d$ since adding $d$ to itself $n/d$ times would yield something such as $d(n/d)=n\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

It turns out that every cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ so that our intuition with the integers and number theory will carry over into arbitrary cyclic groups.

Comment: great very nice explanation !